# Get IIS binding information from Winforms App

Tags: c#, winforms, iis

I have a Winforms App that should interact with a web API installed into the local IIS. Until now, I have just called `http://localhost/myappdir/api/SomeController` and it worked for all people because IIS was installed in default configuration.

Now we had the first install where the binding of the IIS "Default Web Site" has been changed by the user:

- localhost
- https protocol only
- Port 54321

How can I read that information from inside my Winforms application, so that I can construct the URL name `https://localhost:54321/...`? (The Winforms App cannot be run with normal user rights, so it will be run with administrator privileges, if that matters.)

Comment: If the user changes the local config, then lets them change the config in your app too, put these in the settings.

Comment: Jexus Manager is open source, so you can dig its source code to learn how to do so via MWA API. http://JexusManager.com